# PowerBI Split Text Using DAX by Hyphen

Tags: string, powerbi, dax

I have a column of product. All the values in product follows the rule of "product_category_productname"

```
product_shampoo_natural_shampoo
product_toothpaste_super_white_toothpaste
product_food_children_food
```

I want to turn them into

```
Shampoo Natural Shampoo
Toothpaste Super White Toothpaste
Food Children Food
```

So basically, the idea is to split by hyphen, and then pick the second word till the end. And in the meantime, use upper case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("VYpRCsAgDMXu4vduJFLKdFRwvlIru/7GYMj+kpAYgxry3J2G8KkAdfZp3D4PaVuPAy7KwwuNqcXokvrwyr/7ADLtUlu20l8LKd0=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type", "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("_", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Column1.1", "Column1.2", "Column1.3", "Column1.4", "Column1.5"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Column1.1", type text}, {"Column1.2", type text}, {"Column1.3", type text}, {"Column1.4", type text}, {"Column1.5", type text}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type1",{"Column1.1"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

[image: Solution]

Comment: I want to use DAX instead of using Power Query. Like MID or LEFT, SUBSTITUTE functions.

Comment: Splitting a string dynamically based on a delimiter (on each delimiter) is a data wrangling task. DAX on the other hand, is a language for business analysis. DAX does offer some wrangling capabilities but splitting string dynamiclly on each delimiter is not one of them. It is definitely not one of DAX's intended use. On the other hand, if you use Power Query/ Databricks / R/ Python they have more robust data wrangling capabilities including the one you are asking for. Utilizing DAX to split string requires a lot of MID/LEFT/RIGHT/REPLACE like string opeartions and

Comment: it would still not be dynamic after that to my knowledge.